# Mochimedia leaderboard on iOS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, leaderboard

I have ported a Flash game over iPhone and the game is working very well. Now the hard part is we would like to integrate mochimedia leaderboard. I googled and did not find answer to my requirements. I know we can not load external swf contains Action Script in flash running on iOS. But is there any other workaround to integrate mochimedia leaderboard or if they have any swc to be dropped in the project. I just post the question to make sure if its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a talk with Mochi media support and it is not possible.